# sqlite not update all the attributes

Tags: android, sqlite

i am creating an android app that stores tasks attributes into DB. task table has two primary keys (task_name,category) and 3 other attributes.

when i update the task, only the other three attributes got updated, but the primary keys not.

i have another table (todayTasks) that has two foreign keys (taskName, taskCategory) references these two primary key (task_name,category) on update cascade on delete cascade.

```
CREATE TABLE category_table (category_name text primary key not null, start_time_hour integer not null, start_time_minute integer not null, end_time_hour integer not null, end_time_minute integer not null);

CREATE TABLE task_table (task_name text not null, category text not null, priority text not null, time_in_H integer not null, time_in_M integer not null, PRIMARY KEY(task_name, category), FOREIGN KEY(category) REFERENCES category_table(category_name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE todayTasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,taskName TEXT , taskCategory TEXT ,taskHour INTEGER, taskMinute INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(taskName, taskCategory) REFERENCES task_table(task_name, category) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

here is the update method on SchedulerHelper.java (the DB)

```
 public int updateTask(Task task) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TASK_NAME, task.task_name);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TASK_CATEGORY, task.category);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TASK_PRIORITY, task.priority);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME_IN_HOUR, task.time_in_H);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME_IN_MINUTES, task.time_in_M);
    int test = sqliteDatabase.update(TASK_TABLE, contentValues,
            COLUMN_TASK_NAME + " ='"
                    + task.task_name + "' AND " + 
                    COLUMN_TASK_CATEGORY + " ='" + task.category
                    + "'", null);
    if (test > -1) {
        cont.startService(new Intent(cont, Planning.class));
    }
```

i call it from an activity like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

 Task editedTask = new Task(name_editText_value,category_value,
                        priority_value,hours_value,
                        minutes_value);

    int test;
    test = schedulerHelper.updateTask(editedTask);
    if (test != -1) {
        startService(new Intent(this, myService.class));}
```

where is the problem? why i can not update (name) and (category)?

Comment: Because whatever it is you're doing to update, you're doing it wrong. How can anybody help you if you keep your code a secret?

Comment: @CL thanks for you note. i dont think it is important for this query and i just update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the rows to update, you are using `task.task_name` and `task.category`:

```java
        COLUMN_TASK_NAME + " ='"
                + task.task_name + "' AND " + 
                COLUMN_TASK_CATEGORY + " ='" + task.category
                + "'"
```

The values with which the row is updated *also* are `task.task_name` and `task.category`:

```java
contentValues.put(COLUMN_TASK_NAME, task.task_name);
contentValues.put(COLUMN_TASK_CATEGORY, task.category);
```

In other words, this code always writes the *same* values that the row already has.

When these two values in a `Task` object are changed, the row in the database still has the old values, and must be searched for with these old values.
To be able to change these two values in the database, you need to remember the old values so that you can use them for the `update` selection:

```java
public int updateTask(Task task, String old_name, String old_cat) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TASK_NAME, task.task_name);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TASK_CATEGORY, task.category);
    ...
    int test = sqliteDatabase.update(TASK_TABLE, contentValues,
        COLUMN_TASK_NAME + " = ? AND " + 
        COLUMN_TASK_CATEGORY + " = ?",
        new String[] { old_name, old_cat });
    ...
}
```